# Python powerbiclient package: error 404 when trying to open a report through report and workspace ID's

Tags: python, powerbi

I am trying to access a power BI report using powerbiclient Python package and print the report details.

The code I use is:

```
from powerbiclient import Report
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication
from powerbiclient.authentication import InteractiveLoginAuthentication

# Power BI authentication
authentication = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()    

# Workspace ID and Report ID
workspace_id = "fbc74da3-baf6-49e1-85f8-cd652e29eafa"
report_id = "f0273fd2-5db7-4cec-9bb2-32fa8c5c366e"

# Create an instance of Power BI Report
report = Report(workspace_id=workspace_id, report_id=report_id, auth=authentication)

# Interact with the report
# For example, get the report details
report_details = report.get_report()

# Print the report name
print(f"Report Name: {report_details.name}")

# Perform other read-only operations as needed
```

when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Exception: Could not get embed URL: Get embed URL failed with status code 404

I have already checked if I have the viewer rights to see the report I want to open and I do, and if I use edge to open the reports I do it successfully, so it is not a problem of permissions either.

Just so you see that there is no error on the provided ID's (workspace and report), the URL of the report is:

> "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/apps/fbc74da3-baf6-49e1-85f8-cd652e29eafa/reports/f0273fd2-5db7-4cec-9bb2-32fa8c5c366e/ReportSectionc782b700c606e723d710?experience=power-bi"

Is there anything wrong in my code?